# RND generator on SIM card: is it available outside (for Android for instance)?

Tags: android, gsm, javacard

Fuzzy question here.
I know that some smart-cards (including SIM cards) can contain random number generator. But I cannot get any information about that. Is it possible to get random numbers outside of SIM card? For instance, I want to create Android App, which asks SIM card somehow (using APDU commands for example) for random number, then app uses it as intended. Is it possible? I mean, is this generator accessible outside? And if so, what the command should be used?
I'll be very grateful for any hints and links.

Comment: Why can't you simply use the `Random` object?

Comment: According to my information, Random Generator on SIM card is secure in contrast to Random object.

Comment: What do you mean by "secure"? A random number is a number. Which kind of security are you talking about?

Comment: secure in what sense?

Comment: There are two types of random generators. The mostly used type is a pseudo-random number generator. It takes system date and similar data to calculate number which just looks as random, but really it isn't. Second type is a hardware random number generator. It takes unpredictable physical value as a source to generate number. For example, in OneRNG device avalanche diode is used (as a first source). This diode switches on and off _really_ unpredictably. AFAIK, smart card (including SIM) contains really unpredictable random number generator.

Comment: Google keywords: `sim card rng android`

Comment: I googled many times before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** you can install a Java Card Applet on the SIM card then you can use the methods of [RandomData](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/security/RandomData.html) to retrieve data from the SIM card. Note that normally you will have to use the deprecated methods / constants as a lot of the functions were created specifically for Java Card version 3.0.5. You can use this functionality to create an APDU interface. Usually you would implement the ISO/IEC 7816-4 GET CHALLENGE APDU for this.

You can also cheat a bit if the card supports Global Platform: the GP INITIALIZE UPDATE platform INITIALIZE UPDATE APDU in the end returns a "Card challenge" as part of the response data. That way you can access the RNG, but only for 6 bytes at a time. Worse, the SIM card may think it is under attack and perform counter measures, which in the worst case could destroy your SIM, depending on the implementation.

Comment: Thorough answer! Exactly that I wanted, thanks a lot!